# Python: How to Switch Case with Function Call for Pygame Display

Tags: python, function, pygame, switch-statement

I am trying to do a simple application of calling the same functions with different arguments.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text, size, x, y): 
    #print(pygame.font.get_fonts())
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, size) 
    text_surface, text_rectangle = text_objects(text, font) 
    text_rectangle.center = (x, y) 
    gameDisplay.blit(text_surface, text_rectangle) 

def countdown(count_case):
    
    print("Checking Case")
    print(count_case)

    switcher={
            1: message_display("starting in 5", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
            2: message_display("starting in 4", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
            3: message_display("starting in 3", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
            4: message_display("starting in 2", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
            5: message_display("starting in 1", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2)
            }
    func = switcher.get(count_case,"Invalid Countdown")
    return func()
```

I am able to init the Pygame screen and pass `count_case` correctly into the `countdown()` function by checking through `print()`.

However, I am mainly unaware of the syntax for properly calling and executing the `message_display` functions based on `count_case`'s value; 1 to 5. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

> ```py
> message_display("starting in 5", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2)
> ```

is a function call. Therefore you actually store the return values of `message_display` in the dictionary. Just store a tuple with the arguments:

```py
switcher = {
    1: ("starting in 5", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
    2: ("starting in 4", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
    3: ("starting in 3", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
    4: ("starting in 2", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2),
    5: ("starting in 1", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2)
}
```

Use the asterisk (`*`) operator ("unzip") to call the function:

```py
message_display(*switcher[count_case])
```

---

`countdown` function:

```py
def countdown(count_case):
    
    print("Checking Case")
    print(count_case)

    switcher={
        1: ("starting in 5", 40, display_width // 2, (display_height + 400) // 2),
        2: ("starting in 4", 40, display_width // 2, (display_height + 400) // 2),
        3: ("starting in 3", 40, display_width // 2, (display_height + 400) // 2),
        4: ("starting in 2", 40, display_width // 2, (display_height + 400) // 2),
        5: ("starting in 1", 40, display_width // 2, (display_height + 400) // 2)
    }
    return message_display(*switcher[count_case])
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a dict/switch at all. You can format the displayed string based on the input instead

```
def countdown(count_case):
    if count_case < 1 or count_case > 5:
        raise ValueError("count_case must be between 1 and 5")
    return message_display(f"starting in {6 - count_case}", 40, display_width / 2, (display_height + 400) / 2)
```

Comment: Hi @Rabbid76 & lain Shelvington, thanks so much for the prompt reply in teaching me about the logic error, really appreciate it. But as Rabbid76's answers more on fixing the switch-case, I will put his as the official answer for this switch-case thread, nonetheless, thanks so much lain Shelvington, for providing a nice alternative, should have thought of that tooz 